# What is up with the World Map?

Tags: guilty-crown

In episode 10, inside General Yan's room there is a world map. The thing I got confused with is that, the story takes place in Tokyo but what the hack is with this map? Why doesn't it have the original world map?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a world map. It's a map of Japan (tilted about 45° clockwise).

[image: Road map of Japan.]

Comment: This question is a bit unrelated but if your Japanese could you answer it too. Is it a regular thing to show Japan as 45° clockwise in a map or the regular style is the one you posted?

Comment: I'm not Japanese, but I notice that typically the map is rotated somewhat (just not this far). You can see some Japanese maps of Japan [on Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=日本の地図) which might help answer your question. (I think the primary reason it is rotated in the show is because his map is very thin height-wise.)

Comment: I believe it's commonly rotated so that it fits on a page easier for maps